# Populating datatable from an Array's

Tags: c#

I have three arrays as mentioned below. Trying to populate the datatable. But the output was not expected.

needed in this Format

[image]

```
AnalyteNames = new string[] { "NA", "K", "CL" };

Units =  "MML";

values= new string[]{"14", "15","16"}
```

The below was the written code.

```
int count = 0;
for (int col = 0; col < dataSave.Columns.Count; col++)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (col == 0)
    {
        for (int row = 1; row < dataSave.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
        {
            dr[col] = CheckedAnalytes[i];
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 1)
    {
        i = 0;
        for (int row = 1; row < dataSave.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
        {
            dr[col] = SelectedUnits;
        }
    }

    if (count == 2)
    {
        i = 0;
        for (int row = 1; row < dataSave.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
        {
            dr[col] = values[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I see only 2 arrays

Comment: @Zohar Peled, modified the second one from array to string.

Comment: What is `dr`? Where is it assigned?

Comment: `yourArraySource.Select(x=> new yourTableEntity{ Prop1= x.Prop1});`then a simple db.yourTableEntity.InsertOnSubmit(newLine); db.SubmitChanges();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming three arrays with the same length:

```
var analyteNames = new string[] { "NA", "K", "CL" };
var units = new string[]{"MML", "MML", "MML"};
var values = new string[]{"14", "15","16"};
```

And a data table with three columns:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("analyteNames", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("units", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("values", typeof(string));
```

You can use a single loop, using the `DataRowCollection` [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload that accepts `params object[]`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < analyteNames.Length; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(analyteNames[i], units[i], values[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I'll populate a Custom List insert Values into it and the populate DataTable()

Custom List

```
public class Values
{
  public int value1
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string value2
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string value3
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

Next Populate the List

```
List<Values> list = new List<Values>();
list.Add(new Values{
    value1 = 1,
    value2 = "",
    value3 = ""
});
```

Next Populate your DataTable()

```
var dt = new DateTable();

  dt.Columns.Add(Header1, typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add(Header2, typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add(Header3, typeof(string));

foreach(var item in list)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(item.value1,item.value2,item.value3);
}
```